# Adobe Fonts file format

Tags: fonts, adobe, creative-cloud

I know that when adding font from Creative Cloud the font files are a bit hidden on the machine at :
Windows: C:\Users<your user name>\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\CoreSync\plugins\livetype\r

Still, the files are without extention, when i rename to add the .otf extension, the files seems to be not recognized as such by any format checker and cannot be converte to woff or other.

What are these extenstionless file format?